# При подключении к wifi asp.net не видит appsettings.json

Tags: файлы, asp.net, файловая-система, wifi, защита

Столкнулся с очень интересной ситуацией, при подключении к общедоступному wi-fi, asp.net приложение перестает находить файл appsettings.json - Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path').
Как думаете в чем может быть дело? Мое предположение, что макбук пытается защитить этот файл от общедоступной сети и поэтому не дает и моему приложению его прочитать.